# how to update GRN_Tb in c#

Tags: c#

i can't mines qty of GRN_Tb when click save button

try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Invoice_Tb(Invoice_ID,Drug_ID,Drug_Name,Qty,Price,Total)VALUES(@Invoice_ID,@Drug_ID,@Drug_Name,@Qty,@Price,@Total)", cn);

```
            command.Parameters.Add("@Invoice_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = INVOICEtb_IN.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Drug_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CODEcb_IN.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Drug_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NAMEcb_IN.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int).Value = QTYtb1_IN.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UNITPRICEtb1_IN.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TOTALtb1_IN.Text;

            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE GRN_Tb WHERE qty -'"+QTYtb1_IN.Text+"'", cn);


            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {

                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
            UNITPRICEtb1_IN.Clear();
            ds.Clear();
            LordItems();
        }
        catch (InvalidExpressionException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem Occuted whil Connection DB", "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your SQL's query, maybe this is wrong here:

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE GRN_Tb WHERE qty -'"+QTYtb1_IN.Text+"'", cn);
```

Where part——qty-？

I think it should be：

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE GRN_Tb set qty=qty-"+QTYtb1_IN.Text +" where……", cn);
```

And you should use SqlParameter instead of string's combinations to avoid SQL injections. Don't forget to add your where request at "where……". If you don't have where conditions, please ignore it by directly using:

```
  SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE GRN_Tb set qty=qty-"+QTYtb1_IN.Text, cn);
```

Comment: thanks.. but i wont to mines text box value from qty value in grn_tb